# Discord.js - Cannot get user or member by username from client object

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

In Discord.js, I am passing a client into the following:

```
async function get_remindmes(client) { 
  const outstanding_remindmes = await Remindmes.get_outstanding();
  for (let x of outstanding_remindmes) {
    let user = client.users.cache.find(y => String(y.username)+'#'+String(y.discriminator) === x.username);
  }
  return;
}
```

I *can* console.log the `outstanding_remindmes` array from within this function, and client.users.cache.find seems to work in other ways from within this function, but I can't seem to get `user` here to be anything other than `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `x` variable is an object with a username and discriminator, but you're only using `x.username` to compare to `y`'s username *and* discriminator. Should you be comparing the strings like this?

```
let user = client.users.cache.find(y => (y.username + "#" + y.discriminator) === (x.username + "#" + x.discriminator))
```

However, I'm not sure about the circumstances but it's much easier to compare users by using the user id (and it's better practice - users can change their names and even discriminators, but id will always be the same). Actually, if you have the user ids you can simply use the `get` function on `client.users.cache`, because the cache is a collection where the keys of all the elements are the user ids. For example:

```
let user = client.users.cache.get(x.id);
```

All you need to do is store the user ids in each of the entries of the `outstanding_remindmes` object.

Comment: I should have been more clear, the username property on the ```x``` object is the "full" username - the username plus '#' plus the discriminator. Thanks, I will try storing users by id instead and see if I can retrieve them that way.

Comment: Yep, just storing id's and using ```.get(x.user_id)``` solves it, thank you!